# fatal error: Eigen/Core: No such file or directory

Tags: ros, eigen, rosdep, rosmake, laser-geometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use Ubuntu 12.04 and Fuerte and for some reason, I cannot include laser_geometry.h from my code. When I do so, laser_geometry.h includes `<Eigen/Core>`, which makes rosmake fail when compiling my package:

```
  In file included from /home/robot/nifti_systems/bleeding-edge/stacks/nifti_ui/foo/src/foo.cpp:5:0:
  /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/laser_pipeline/laser_geometry/include/laser_geometry/laser_geometry.h:46:22: fatal error: Eigen/Core: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
  make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/foo.dir/src/foo.o] Error 1
```

Package foo has these dependencies in its manifest:

```
<depend package="roscpp"/>
<depend package="laser_geometry"/>
```

And I also tried with this (which should be unnecessary since it is already in the manifest of package laser_geometry):

```
<rosdep name="eigen"/>
```

I called `rosdep install` before `rosmake`, and it says that all dependencies are installed. I tried removing ROS_NOBUILD from laser_geometry, and I can build that package without a problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44140/fatal-error:-eigen/core:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 867 on 2012-09-19

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a different solution than the one from tlinder, although it is related.

The [migration web page](http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Migration#Eigen_can.27t_be_found) mentions that if your package exports headers that use Eigen, you must export the Eigen flag. This is currently not done by package laser_geometry. I tried it on my set-up, i.e. I changed

```
<export>
<cpp cflags="-I${prefix}/include" 
     lflags="-Wl,-rpath,${prefix}/lib -L${prefix}/lib -llaser_geometry"/>
</export>
```

to

```
<export>
<cpp cflags="`pkg-config --cflags eigen3` -I${prefix}/include" 
     lflags="-Wl,-rpath,${prefix}/lib -L${prefix}/lib -llaser_geometry"/>
</export>
```

and it solved the problem. If I'm not mistaken, it was just forgotten in laser_geometry. I filed a ticket for it: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5566.

---

Originally posted by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) with karma: 867 on 2012-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look in the migration web page [here](http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Migration).

Eigen is in fuerte differently used then in prior versions:

> Starting with Fuerte, the new pattern
> to find Eigen in a CMakeLists.txt file
> is:
>
> find_package(Eigen REQUIRED)
>
> include_directories(${EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIRS})
> >
> > add_definitions(${EIGEN_DEFINITIONS})

---

Originally posted by [tlinder](https://answers.ros.org/users/2680/tlinder/) with karma: 663 on 2012-09-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you very much for bringing up and resolving this issue. We have incorporated the bugfix into the Fuerte release 1.4.5.

We've also addressed this for the Groovy release, where the stack has moved to the new catkin build system.

---

Originally posted by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) with karma: 1444 on 2012-10-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On Ubuntu 14.04 and Indigo use Eigen3 instead of Eigen

find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})

---

Originally posted by [Nomad](https://answers.ros.org/users/19317/nomad/) with karma: 53 on 2016-01-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4